# Android alert dialog icon align to right

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I would like to ask is it possible to **align alert dialog icon to right** without using **custom dialog**?

Any help is appreciated.

```
                    AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                    .setTitle(" ")
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_info_256)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    result.confirm();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    result.cancel();
                                }
                            })
                    .create()
                    .show();
```

Comment: There is no method to set the position of Icon. One year ago I also tried to do that ! But unfortunately custom dialog is the only solution. If you need any help for custom dialog let me know. Happy Coding !

Comment: You can use the method `setCustomTitle` to use a custom view in the title panel